# Returning fewer in ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem I was up all night trying to solve but I did not find any information anywhere hope you can help me.

I have a function in ajax returning latitude and longitude of all users within a php array, it operates in all cool, but I need to take this data and include within another function that calculates the distance of a major coordinate with all returned coordinates from the bank

this feature is also working very well, my problem is that I need to take these values and compare to see which is the shortest distance but when I try to retrieve only the lowest value it returns all the values that were calculated

it returns in my console these numbers

for the distance to calculate the latitude and longitude of 2 registered users in the database

0.38103420280036954
  1.1341204506826572

but they should only return the 0.38103420280036954 number is the smallest number of the function.

I do not know what to do I'm all night looking for and trying without success.

Here is my javascript code

```
$.ajax({


  type : 'POST',
  data : formula,
  url : 'http://10.0.0.119/melleve/statusorig2.php',
  success : function(data){


    var retorno = JSON.parse(data);




$.each(retorno, function (index, value) {

  var latitude = value.latitude;
  var longitude = value.longitude;







var lat1 = -22.8650697;
var lat2 = latitude;

var long1 = -43.287510499999996;
var long2 = longitude;

var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
var theta = long1 - long2;
var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
var dist = Math.sin(radlat1)*Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
dist = Math.acos(dist);

dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;


var finaldist = dist * 1.609344;


var numeros = [finaldist];
var ok = Math.min.apply(Math, numeros);

console.log(ok);







});






  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    //debugger;
  }
  //,complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
   // debugger;
  //}

})
```

here is my php

```
$carmodel = $_POST['carmodel'];



 $sql = "SELECT * FROM cadast_moto WHERE carmodel = '$carmodel'"; 

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$encode = array();

while ($res = $result->fetch_array()) {

$arr = array('idmoto' => $res['idmoto'], 'nomemoto' => $res['nomemoto'], 'latitude' => $res['latitude'], 'longitude' => $res['longitude']);


$encode[] = $arr;

//echo (json_encode($arr));

}
```

Comment: The problem is that you use the `console.log()` inside the `each` loop. That's why it print all the result. You have to store all the result and do a `Math.min()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing the minimum within the `$.each`, meaning that it will be called multiple times. Also, your array only contains one element `numeros = [finaldist]`. You probably want something like:

```
var distances = $.map(arrayOfValues, function(value) { 
   /* do calcualation for one longitude latitude pair */
   return finaldist;
});

var smallestNumber = Math.min.apply(Math, distances);
```

If you're not familiar with jQuery.map, you can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/).

Comment: Perfectly as I needed, is now working as a glove, thanks even his answer was 10000000